# How to simplify ternary expression

Tags: java, ternary

Is it possible to simplify this min + ternary expression by a one liner?

```
BigDecimal min = x.getMinimum();
BigDecimal result = otherValue.compareTo(min) > 0 ? otherValue : min;
```

Comment: Can you use [`BigDecimal.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#max(java.math.BigDecimal))?

Comment: As khelwood already suggested `BigDecimal.max(...)` would be the way to go. In fact, the source is very similar to your code: `public BigDecimal max(BigDecimal val) { return (compareTo(val) >= 0 ? this : val); }`

Comment: Note that your code has one difference to `otherValue.max(min)`: when the comparison yields 0 your code would return `min` while `otherValue.max(min)` would return `otherValue`. Numerically they both represent the same value but they are _not_ equal, e.g. if min would be `2.00` and `otherValue` would be `2.0` (same numeric value but different scale)  - so if you are ok with that then use `otherValue.max(min)`, otherwise you could roll your own version of `max(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want [`BigDecimal.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#max(java.math.BigDecimal)).

```
BigDecimal result = otherValue.max(x.getMinimum());
```

This will give you whichever is the greater of `otherValue` and `x.getMinimum()`.

(If neither is greater than the other, it will return `otherValue` rather than `x.getMinimum()`, but that is probably close enough to what you want — the alternative would be `x.getMinimum().max(otherValue)`.)

Comment: You're welcome - Thought I'd just fix the typo instead of making a fuss :)

Comment: I'd suggest adding one information for completeness: there is a difference between the OP's code and `BigDecimal.max` which _might_ be relevant - see my comment on the question. You're free to copy - I'll delete it afterwards ;)

Comment: @Thomas I've added a note about that detail: feel free to leave your more thorough comment in place.

Comment: Ok, I'll leave it there. If I could you'd get another +1 for the alternative :)